# Trouble with CUDA on notebook with Optimus

Tags: cuda, nvidia, hybrid

I've installed CUDA toolkit v4.0 RC2 on my ASUS N61J with GeForce GT 325M (Win7 x64).
Managed to integrate Cuda with Visual Studio 2010.

I try to run an example code stolen from here http://llpanorama.wordpress.com/2008/05/21/my-first-cuda-program/. The program compiles and runs but CUDA returns error:

```
cuda driver version is insufficient for cuda runtime version
```

Ok, i do some googling and decide to install the latest developer driver. Doesn't help anyway - the same error =\

Maybe the program doesn't "see" that i have a CUDA-compatible hardware? I need your help! =)

Answer (score 1):

The installation of the latest drivers together with the latest CUDA toolkit is correct. Otherwise you might get inconsistencies.

For the mobile GPUs there is an additional requirement of Minimum 256MB of graphics memory (http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_gpus.html). You can check the amount of graphics memory you have by using a tool like **[GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/)**.

Comment: i have a "nvidia cuda" sticker on the frame =)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried CUDA on Visual studio yet.
I have the same problem on Linux.

The problem can be Optimus technology, which switches off the GPU to reduce power consumption.
Optimus technology is not supported on Linux.

But it should work on Windows. And there is an option to switch on GPU for specific applications. Turn it on for VS and try again and Check more details on NVidia forums.

Cuda is officially supported on GT325M http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_geforce_gt_325m_us.html

Comment: i tried running compiled application with forced use of nvidia gpu. doesn't help. will do futher research. i have left a topic on nvidia forum some time ago - nothing useful yet.